# iOS Google Map SDK not scrolling smooth during zoom in/out

Tags: ios, google-maps, smooth-scrolling

```
func setMarkeronmap(isFitAllPins : Bool)
{
    var myTagValue : Int = 0

    var bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds()

    // loop for set marker icon image
    for item in self.arrFirstThirty
    {
        if let jsonDict = item as? NSDictionary
        {
            var floatLat  = Double()
            var floatLong = Double()
            if let temp = jsonDict.value(forKey: "Latitude") as? String {
                floatLat = Double ((jsonDict.value(forKey: "Latitude") as? String)!)!
                floatLong = Double((jsonDict.value(forKey: "Longtitude") as? String)!)!
            }
            else {
                floatLat = Double ((jsonDict.value(forKey: "Latitude") as? NSNumber)!)
                floatLong = Double((jsonDict.value(forKey: "Longtitude") as? NSNumber)!)
            }
            self.Mapview.isMyLocationEnabled = true

            let mapMarker = GMSMarker()
            mapMarker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(floatLat
                , floatLong)
            bounds = bounds.includingCoordinate(mapMarker.position)

            self.myImageView.image = UIImage (named: "\((jsonDict.value(forKey: "CompanyBrand") as! String).lowercased())_map_pin")

            var sourceView = UIView()
            sourceView = self.viewMarker
            let copiedView: UIView = sourceView.copyView()
            copiedView.tag = myTagValue

            let image = self.image(with: copiedView)
            mapMarker.icon = image
            mapMarker.tracksViewChanges = true
            mapMarker.map = self.Mapview

            mapMarker.userData = myTagValue
            mapMarker.zIndex = Int32(myTagValue)
            myTagValue += 1
        }
    }
```

If I keep only above code then map scrolling is too smooth as required. But when I add below code then map scrolling is not smooth.

```
// loop for set marker iconView
    myTagValue = 10000
    for item in self.arrFirstThirty
    {
        if let jsonDict = item as? NSDictionary
        {
            var floatLat  = Double()
            var floatLong = Double()
            if let temp = jsonDict.value(forKey: "Latitude") as? String {
                floatLat = Double ((jsonDict.value(forKey: "Latitude") as? String)!)!
                floatLong = Double((jsonDict.value(forKey: "Longtitude") as? String)!)!
            }
            else {
                floatLat = Double ((jsonDict.value(forKey: "Latitude") as? NSNumber)!)
                floatLong = Double((jsonDict.value(forKey: "Longtitude") as? NSNumber)!)
            }


            let mapMarker = GMSMarker()
            mapMarker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(floatLat
                , floatLong)
            bounds = bounds.includingCoordinate(mapMarker.position)

            Mapview.needsUpdateConstraints()


            var strCurrType = String("Euro")

            if Defaults[PDUserDefault.CurrencyNameEnglish] != nil && Defaults[PDUserDefault.CurrencyRate] != nil
            {
                strCurrType = Defaults[PDUserDefault.CurrencyNameSymbol]!
                let abc = ("\((jsonDict.value(forKey: "FuelPrice") as? String)!)")
                let strPrice = Float(abc.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: ".", options: .literal, range: nil))
                var updatedPrice = Float(Defaults[PDUserDefault.CurrencyRate]!)! * strPrice!
                updatedPrice = (updatedPrice * 1000).rounded() / 1000

                var finalPrice = String.init(format: "%.3f", updatedPrice)

                if Defaults[PDUserDefault.LanguageType] == "1"
                {
                    finalPrice = finalPrice.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: ".")
                }
                else
                {
                    finalPrice = finalPrice.replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: ",")
                }

                self.lblmarkername.text = ("\(finalPrice) \(strCurrType!)")

                let strokeTextAttributes = [
                    NSStrokeColorAttributeName : UIColor.init(red: 1.0/255.0, green: 123.0/255.0, blue: 146.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0),NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white,NSStrokeWidthAttributeName : -3.0,] as [String : Any]

                self.lblmarkername.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: ("\(finalPrice) \(strCurrType!)"), attributes: strokeTextAttributes)
            }
            else
            {
                strCurrType = Defaults[PDUserDefault.CurrencyNameSymbol]!
                let abc = ("\((jsonDict.value(forKey: "FuelPrice") as? String)!)")
                var strmyPrice = Float(abc.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: ".", options: .literal, range: nil))
                strmyPrice = (strmyPrice! * 1000).rounded() / 1000

                var finalPrice = String.init(format: "%.3f", strmyPrice!)

                if Defaults[PDUserDefault.LanguageType] == "1"
                {
                    finalPrice = finalPrice.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: ".")
                }
                else
                {
                    finalPrice = finalPrice.replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: ",")
                }

                self.lblmarkername.text = ("\(finalPrice) \(strCurrType!)")

                let strokeTextAttributes = [
                    NSStrokeColorAttributeName : UIColor.init(red: 1.0/255.0, green: 123.0/255.0, blue: 146.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0),NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white,NSStrokeWidthAttributeName : -3.0,] as [String : Any]

                self.lblmarkername.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: ("\(finalPrice) \(strCurrType!)"), attributes: strokeTextAttributes)
            }

            var sourceView = UIView()
            sourceView = self.viewMarker2
            let copiedView: UIView = sourceView.copyView()
            copiedView.tag = myTagValue
            mapMarker.iconView = copiedView
            mapMarker.tracksViewChanges = true

            mapMarker.map = self.Mapview

            mapMarker.userData = myTagValue
            mapMarker.zIndex = Int32(myTagValue)
            myTagValue += 1

            markerArray.add(mapMarker)
        }
    }

    if isFitAllPins
    {
        let update = GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds, withPadding: 80)
        self.Mapview.animate(with: update)
    }
}
```

Using first loop, I had added marker with image only. And then in second loop I have added prices over the market image because I have to keep prices always on top without hiding behind the marker image. But if I add prices this way, Map scrolling is not smooth. So please anyone can help me on this?

Comment: so callouts (with data)on the marker should display by default along with markers when the map loads is this your requirement ? so your  doing second loop!

Comment: I am doing second loop to add prices over the Map because I have to keep prices text always on top so any marker should not hide any prices.

Comment: show me screenshot

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PBTrDPTISN4  Here is the video of it.